# current running time with $time

Tags: php, jquery

I want to set current time with $time.
Like I am using

```
$time = date("H:i:s");
```

When using current running time:
I am using this code:

```
<script>
function pad(num) {return ("0" + num).slice(-2);}
function time1() {
var today = new Date(),
h = today.getHours(),
m = today.getMinutes(),
s = today.getSeconds();

h = h % 12;
h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
clk.innerHTML = h + ':' + 
pad(m) + ':' + 
pad(s) + ' ' + 
(h >= 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}
window.onload = function() {
var clk = document.getElementById('clk');
t = setInterval(time1, 500);
}
</script>
```

```
<span id="clk" style="background:white; padding:3px;"></span>
```

I want to use like below:

```
$time = date("H:i:s");
```

$clk = ?(how to write code here for the code above)

Actually I want to use $clk like below:

```
<input id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo $clk; ?>"/>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, what's your end goal?

Comment: I want to use current running time  as <?php echo $clk; ?>    What will I  write code for $clk

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to set a PHP variable with a Javascript value.  You cant do that.  Javascript runs in the viewers browser.  PHP runs on the server.  You probably need to read up on the differences between the two to help you understand this better.  Here is a link to get you started.  http://www.michaelrauch.net/2011/06/php-vs-javascript-what-are-the-differences/

Comment: I want to use <?php echo $clk; ?>. for `$clk` what will I write? I mean $clk=....

Comment: I dont understand what you want I guess.  In your <script> above, you have it updating every 500ms.  Now you just wanting a value for an input?  Do you want the input to update? What is the end goal for what you want to have as the value for the <input>?

Comment: May I use like   $clk= (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();   but it is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to get a PHP variable ($clk) to equal what the current time is in Javascript?

Comment: Actually I mean that. as $time = date("H:i:s"); here time is not updated every second except when onload. I want to get updated time every second as $clk=(I will write code here)     this is my input::  <input id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo $clk; ?>"/>

Comment: Ok, you cant do that.  Javascript runs in the browser on the viewers side.  PHP runs on the server side.  You cant have a value in Javascript automatically set a PHP variable like that.  You need to understand the difference between the two and how they both work.  Here is a link that may help with that. http://www.michaelrauch.net/2011/06/php-vs-javascript-what-are-the-differences/